# Replacing TO-220 MOSFET with SMD DPAK

Tags: mosfet

This MOSFET [IRFBG30](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/427/91124-86052.pdf) is being used in an old design. It even has a little heat sink attached. The FET is used as a current limiter. During normal operation, a current about 13 mA passes through it. Under certain condition, the same FET is going to switch a 1.4A inductive load for a brief moment. What I'm thinking is to redesign this board and replace that FET, with this one: [IPD95R1K2P7](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IPD95R1K2P7-DS-v02_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462636cc8fb01643b928d27571a) which is a surface mount FET. I would use the PCB as heat sink. I note that the new FET has VDS: 950V and the old one 1000V. But I think this shouldn't be an issue, as I expect the max VDS to reach 900V under some critical/unwanted condition. Of course, this time the IRFBG30 wins. However, the IPD95R1K2P7 has lower RDS.

Is this a good idea?

EDIT: Added the circuit

[image]

Comment: How long is “brief moment”?

Comment: Not sure, but it's short. Probably less than a second as the coil when turned on will remove the main supply.

Comment: Show the circuit, if there is any inductance in the circuit 900V could quickly turn to 1000V with inductive overshoot.

Comment: It will be a dimensioning parameter so you need to define it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the Safe Operating Area (SOA) of IRFBG30 you were using:

[image]

..and finally IPD95R1K2P7:

[image]

Now compare the "10ms or DC" portion of the SOA curve, highlighted in yellow on the last one. The first FET has a constant power SOA limit, that is Vds*Id is constant, which in a log-log graph manifests as a straight line with a downward slope of "10x more volts, 10x less amps."

However, the second FET has double the slope, and since the graph is log this means "10x more volts, **100x less amps**."

This indicates the first FET should be fine for linear operation, but the second FET probably has some localized self heating / hotspot / current hogging phenomena that makes it a lot less robust in linear operation. It's most likely optimized for switching only, at the expense of linear.

Also at 13mA DC, the voltage you intend to use **violates the SOA** by a quite substantial margin so it will probably pop.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful .For high reliability 1200 Volt semiconductors should be used ,so consider a 1200V mosfet or a series string .Remember that modern Powermosfets are not good in the linear mode .Lower RDs on types tend to be worse due to current crowding .Consider a series resister in the drain circuit to reduce device stress.I use a discrete buck converter on such 3 phase applications .

Comment: Ok. However, I don't think there are 1200V FETs available at Surface Mount, so in this case I would stick to Through Hole package.